# For loop how many times work count print in console

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, count

how to Count how many times a for loop runs in javascript and print to console

```
let b = 10;

for(let a = 1; a <= b; a++){
    console.log(a);

    //how to count how many times for loop works

    
}
```

how print console this

console:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
count = 10


if

5
6
7
8
9
10
count = 6
```

how to do this help me

Comment: You don't need to count. You can use math: 10 = 10 - 1 + 1, 6 = 10 - 5 + 1. Work smarter, not harder.

Answer (score 1):

To count the [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)'s iterations, declare a variable, track the count, and increment it within the loop.

```js
let b = 10;
let count = 0;

for (let a = 1; a <= b; a++) {
  console.log(a);
  count++;
}

console.log("count =", count);
```